# sqlBuilder pagination with MyBatis without Limit & Offset in the query

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, dynamicquery

I'm trying to understand how to do dynamic queries for pagination with myBatis in my java spring-boot application

My problem is that the database version of my application is Oracle 11.2 which doesn't support LIMIT & OFFSET in the query.

The only solution I've found to this is using ROWNUM in this way:

```
SELECT *  FROM   
(SELECT te.*, ROWNUM AS rn FROM  TEST_EVENT te  order by te.EVENT_ID)
 a WHERE  a.rn >= #{resultFrom} AND    a.rn <= #{resultTo}
```

However I'm not able to implement inner query with myBatis sqlBuilder.

At least I've tried like this and it gives me compilation error:

```
public String selectTestEventsFromDate(Long dateFrom ,int resultFrom, int resultTo) {
        return new SQL() {{

            SELECT("*");
            FROM(
                SELECT("te.*, ROWNUM AS rn");
                FROM("  TEST_EVENT te");
                if (dateFrom != null) {
                    WHERE("te.TIMESTMP >= #{dateFrom }");
                }
                ORDER_BY("te.EVENT_ID");
            a)
            WHERE  a.rn >= #{resultFrom} AND    a.rn <= #{resultTo}
        }}.toString();
    }
```

**What's the best way to achieve pagination & dynamic queries with Mybatis without using LIMIT & OFFSET in the query?**

Additional code:

In my TestEventMapper.java:

```
    @SelectProvider(type = testEventSqlBuilder.class, method = "selectTestEventsFromDate")
    ArrayList<TestEventEntity> selectTestEventsProvider(Long dateFrom, int resultFrom, int resultTo);
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>${ojdbc.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.dynamic-sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-dynamic-sql</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I generally prefer defining the SQL in the XML file. Easier to write and we can even copy paste the query in to SQL tool to test it. So it would also solve your problem.

Comment: @user2298581 The built-in `SQL` class is pretty basic. The mybatis-dynamic-sql that is in your dependencies supports more advanced syntax. Check out the [details](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql). Also, you can specify `databaseId` in `@SelectProvider` to support multiple DB syntax. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html).